# How to insert thousand separator with `sed`?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, regex, sed

I want to insert thousand separator into a number sequence with `sed` and this ugly RE `sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\(\([0-9]\{3\}\)\(,[0-9]\{3\}\)*\(\.[0-9]*\)\)/\1,\2/;ta' [filename]`.

Is there a more elegant solution?

===========================================================

EDIT

One thing I omitted just now: the number may have a decimal point. Give an example:

123456.7890

I want the result after separating 123,456.7890

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not using sed, but you could try something similar to this:

`echo "10000" | xargs printf "%'d\n"`

Or a solution using sed [from here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/format-numbers-using-bash-672031/):

`echo "2312341" | sed -r ':L;s=\b([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})\b=\1,\2=g;t L'`

Comment: Thanks in advance. The `printf` works fine. while the `sed` version seems cannot handle decimal point correctly.